# Why does being in a C# namespace hide other namespaces that start with an intermediate element of the namespace name?

Tags: c#, namespaces

```
namespace Y
{
  class foo { }
}
                    
namespace X.Z
{
  class bar : Y.foo { }
} // fine
                    
namespace X.Y.Z
{
  class bar2 : Y.foo { }
} // error!, now foo can't be found because it looks for X.Y.foo
```

Is this a c# bug? I would have though being in a namespace just prefixed the names of items declared in the namespace. Apparently something else is happening and I'm not sure it is a good thing.

Comment: Not a bug, use `global::Y.foo;` to disambiguate.  Pick good names, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-namespaces

Comment: Erm, you can just put `using Y;` at the top, then have `class bar2 : foo { }`

Answer (score -1):

So

```
namespace X.Y.Z
{
  class bar2 : Y.foo { }
}
```

Is just shorthand for:

```
namespace X
{    
    namespace Y
    {        
        namespace Z
        {
          class bar2 : Y.foo { }
        }         
    }    
}
```

(Hopefully it's clear why the shorthand is actually valuable.)

So now it comes time to try to resolve the identifier `Y.foo`.  The way C# does this is it always looks at the narrowest possible scope, and if it finds no suitable matches, it moves up a level.  So first it'll look within the definition of `bar2`, and find no suitable candidates.  Then it goes to the next level up to the namespace `X.Y.Z`.  Then up a level again to the namespace `X.Y`.  Now we have something `Y` can match, the namespace itself, and it looks to match the identifier `foo` inside of that, since it's a namespace, and again, finds that there is nothing.

Since there *was* a suitable match for `Y`, it's done.  Anytime an identifier is able to be resolved, even if it errors, it doesn't continue searching for other things that the identifier could resolve to that might not error.

A way to resolve the identifier as you want to is to use the `global::` prefix, which is a keyword that prevents the whole "work inside out" thing from happening and forces the identifier to start from the root and work its way down, allowing you to write `global::Y.foo;` and have it match the type that you want.  You could also add a `using` to either import the namespace or create an alias for the type to resolve the type properly.

Of course the best resolution is to use different namespace names to avoid the ambiguity problem entirely, if you have control over that.